# BBPress Topic Tags

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

We have created a page and called the shortcode [bbp-topic-form] it is displaying form to add new topics. We want topic tags field to behave same as it behaves at back-end (that means we want auto suggestion at front-end with checklist).

Regards
Mayank